# hide td in the range of two id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

have a situation here that have to hide table td in the range of two numbers
using jquery as getting the response from ajax in json format

My Ajax Result is like this

```
[{"start_time":"090000","end_time":"100000"},{"start_time":"123000","end_time":"133000"},{"start_time"
:"160000","end_time":"170000"}]
```

my html is

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="090000"></td>
  <td id="093000"></td>
  :td id will increment in range of 3000
  :
  <td id="180000"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

for example want to hide the div from 090000 to 100000.
how we can ahieve this through jquery

i tried like this

```
$.each(res,function(i,k){
  $("#"+k.start_time).hide();
  $("#"+k.end_time).hide();
})
```

Comment: `$(function(){
    for (var i=090000; i<=100000;i=i+3000){
        $('#id'+i).hide();
    }
});`  Do this and tell if this works or not.This will check after adding 3000 to the ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()`,

```js
$('td').filter(function () {
    return (this.id >= 090000 && this.id <= 100000);
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="090000">hide</td>
  <td id="093000">hide</td>
  <td id="180000">visible</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method like following.

```js
$('td').filter(function () {
    return (+this.id >= 090000 && +this.id <= 100000);
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="090000 ">090000</td>
        <td id="100000">100000</td>
        <td id="200000">200000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('td').each(function() { 
       var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
       if(id >= 90000 && id <= 100000)
       $(this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').each(function() { 
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'))
    if (id >= 90000 && id <= 100000) {
        $(this).hide()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through all td elements, and check if its id is in the range.

```
$("table tr td").each(function(idx, ele){
    var mid = ele.id;
    if (mid >= "090000" && mid <= "100000") {
        $(ele).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the below:

```js
var result = [{
  "start_time": "090000",
  "end_time": "100000"
}, {
  "start_time": "123000",
  "end_time": "133000"
}, {
  "start_time": "160000",
  "end_time": "170000"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var
    st = parseInt(result[i]['start_time'], 10),
    et = parseInt(result[i]['end_time'], 10);

  $('table td')
    .filter(function() {
      var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
      return id >= st && id <= et;
    })
    .css('background', 'red')
    .hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="090000">090000</td>
    <td id="093000">093000</td>
    <td id="180000">180000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```